# Pass parameter values into __construct() when using Restler 3's dependency injection container Scope

Tags: php, dependency-injection, restler

I've got an application which uses the DIC **Pimple** to manage dependency injection; that works great when calling certain methods via command line or internally. However, once I try to call them by an API provided by **Restler**, it begins throwing 500 errors due to the fact that the __construct() was not given the needed parameters. (Note that methods inside a class that has no __construct() or requires no constructor parameters work just fine via API.)

I am trying to use **Restler's** internal DIC called *Scope*, which isn't really working so well. Case in point, I've got something like this in index.php:

```
Scope::register('Kiosk\\Drone\\Drone', function () { 
    return new Kiosk\Drone\Drone(Scope::get('\\Noodlehaus\\Config')); 
});
```

The issue is that **\Noodlehaus\Config** requires the path to a JSON encoded configuration file upon instantiation. Within my application this has already been handled within **Pimple**.

When using my *Main* loader object, which instantiates **Pimple** and populates the container with needed dependencies, I am able to call the same method directly via CLI without any problems like so:

```
$file = __DIR__ . "/config.json";
$main = new Main($file);
$d = new Kiosk\Drone\Drone($main->c['config']);
```

I imagine that the capability for this is there within *Scope*, but without an example or some documentation I have not been able to figure it out. And frankly, I'd like to limit my usage of *Scope* to as little as possible due to the fact that it is built upon a singleton pattern, which sort of defeats the whole idea of using dependency injection in the first place.

Really I'd like to be able to have **Restler** access the methods in my classes and instantiate them using **Pimple**. That would be a score for integration.

Edit:

I have been directed to [this bug/feature request](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/330) for support for an external dependency injection container in **Restler**. The author has implemented it in the upcoming RC6.

I can't say that I am entirely sure about using it yet though. There is an example shown [here in a related bug.](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/423)

```
$objectManager = new MyOwnDependencyInjectionContainer();
Scope::$resolver = function ($className) use ($objectManager) {
    return $context->get($className);
};
$r->addAPIClass('MyOwnApiClass');
```

The author states that an external DIC should be used like so:

```
Scope::$resolver = function ($className) use ($context) {
    return $context->getByType($className);
};
```

I am almost there, it is nearly working. I believe the issue now has something to do with **Restler** dependencies not being loaded by my DIC. As mentioned previously, I am using the dependency injection container **Pimple**. I have an initialization class called Main in which I instantiate Pimple, set up dependencies, load configuration file, etc.

Here are relevant portions of Main.php:

```
class Main {

    private $configFile;
    public $c; // a dependency injection container

    public function __construct($configFile=null){
        $this->configFile = $configFile;
        //create DIC
        $this->c = new Container();

        ...
        }
    ...
    }
```

This is my index.php:

```
<?php

namespace Kiosk;

use Luracast\Restler\Scope;
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$file = __DIR__ . "/config.json";

$main = new Main($file);

$c = $main->c;
Scope::$resolver = function ($className) use ($c) { 
    return $c[$className];
};

$r = new Restler(true,true);
$r->addAPIClass('Luracast\\Restler\\Resources');
$r->addAPIClass('Kiosk\\Drone\\Drone','drone');
$r->handle();

?>
```

This is the error (I can provide stack trace is that will be useful:)

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with   message 'Identifier "Luracast\Restler\Format\JsonFormat" is not defined.' in     /var/www/kitchenkiosk.co/public_html/api/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php:95
```

Thanks for any help that can be provided!

Edit 2:

The problem seems to go deeper than simply not having the dependencies within **Pimple**. I suspect the issue is related to a difference in the structure of DIC's:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with     message 'Identifier "Luracast\Restler\Format\JsonFormat" is not defined.'     in         /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php:95
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/public_html/api/index.php(17): Pimple\Container-        >offsetGet('Luracast\\Restle...')
#1  /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/S cope.php(108): Kiosk\{closure}('Luracast\\Restle...')
#2  /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php(389): Luracast\Restler\Scope::get('JsonFormat')
#3 /var/www/public_html/api/index.php(21): Luracast\Restler\Restler->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat')
#4 {main}
thrown in /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php on line 95
```

Edit 3: These are the new errors after implementing Luracast's suggestion:

```
[$] PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php on line 711
[$] PHP Stack trace:
[$] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/public_html/api/index.php:0
[$] PHP   2. Luracast\Restler\Restler->handle() /var/www/public_html/api/index.php:27
[$] PHP   3. Luracast\Restler\Restler->call() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:304
[$] PHP   4. call_user_func_array:{/var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:1045}() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:1045
[$] PHP   5. Luracast\Restler\Resources->get() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:1045
[$] PHP   6. Luracast\Restler\Resources->_parameter() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php:327
[$] PHP   7. Luracast\Restler\Resources->_model() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php:553
[$] PHP   8. PDO->__construct() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php:711
[$] PHP Warning:  get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given in /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php on line 713
[$] PHP Stack trace:
[$] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/public_html/api/index.php:0
[$] PHP   2. Luracast\Restler\Restler->handle() /var/www/public_html/api/index.php:27
[$] PHP   3. Luracast\Restler\Restler->call() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:304
[$] PHP   4. call_user_func_array:{/var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:1045}() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:1045
[$] PHP   5. Luracast\Restler\Resources->get() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:1045
[$] PHP   6. Luracast\Restler\Resources->_parameter() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php:327
[$] PHP   7. Luracast\Restler\Resources->_model() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php:553
[$] PHP   8. get_object_vars() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php:713
[$] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php on line 715
[$] PHP Stack trace:
[$] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/public_html/api/index.php:0
[$] PHP   2. Luracast\Restler\Restler->handle() /var/www/public_html/api/index.php:27
[$] PHP   3. Luracast\Restler\Restler->call() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:304
[$] PHP   4. call_user_func_array:{/var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:1045}() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:1045
[$] PHP   5. Luracast\Restler\Resources->get() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Restler.php:1045
[$] PHP   6. Luracast\Restler\Resources->_parameter() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php:327
[$] PHP   7. Luracast\Restler\Resources->_model() /var/www/public_html/api/vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Resources.php:553
```

It is probably worthwhile to note that I have implemented a different dependency injection container, one called **PHP-DI**. This one has syntax that is closer to that of Scope, so I figured it would be simpler to get it working with **Restler**. However, I am getting the exact same errors thrown with both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Luracast, I do have the solution now! Fortunately **Restler** RC6 **PHP-DI** are perfectly compatible once they are integrated correctly. The problem was, no surprise, one of my own making.

It was all a matter of the namespace. I had originally defined the namespace *Kiosk* at the beginning of my index.php. Luracast suggest keeping it within the root namespace.

This is the current working index.php:

```
<?php

use Luracast\Restler\Scope;
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
use Kiosk\Main;
use Kiosk\Drone\Drone;

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$file = __DIR__ . "/config.json";

$main = new Main($file);

$c = $main->c;

Scope::register('Kiosk\\Drone\\Drone', function () use ($c) {
    return new DataTable($c->get('config'), $c->get('logger'));
});

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Luracast\\Restler\\Resources');
$r->addAPIClass('Kiosk\\Drone\\Drone','drone');
$r->addAuthenticationClass('Kiosk\\System\\TokenAuth');
$r->handle();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me attempt to find a simpler solution

```
<?php

use Luracast\Restler\Scope;
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$file = __DIR__ . "/config.json";

$main = new Main($file);

$c = $main->c;

Scope::register('Kiosk\\Drone\\Drone', function () use ($c) { 
    return $c['Kiosk\Drone\Drone']; 
}); 

$r = new Restler(true,true);
$r->addAPIClass('Luracast\\Restler\\Resources');
$r->addAPIClass('Kiosk\\Drone\\Drone');
$r->handle();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I am still having difficulties with this.

My index.php file looks pretty much just like what you suggested, but it is throwing a LOT of errors now... all of which seem to be related to being unable to pass parameters into the dependencies.

I've edited my original question to include error logs.